# Relationship between tables in Rails (Double relation with the same table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, erb

I'm new to rails, and I would like to get your help in this issue.

I have two tables Account and Transaction. each transaction shall have from account and to account. so when i add a transaction i shall select from the account table two times to get the FROM and TO accounts (list Selection in new transaction Form).

I'm using scaffold to generate the code and I can add only one relation to the table. Do you how to generate the relation with the account table two times

This is the generation code:

```
$rails g scaffold account a_name:string a_type:string a_amount:float
$rails g scaffold Transaction account_id:integer account_id:integer t_amount:float      t_date:date t_desc:text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two `account_id` columns in the transactions table, `from_account_id` and `to_account_id`, otherwise how will you tell the difference between the two?

```
rails g scaffold Transaction to_account_id:integer from_account_id:integer
```

Then, in your Transaction model, you will need to define the relationship properly:

```
belongs_to :from_account, class_name: 'Account'
belongs_to :to_account, class_name: 'Account'
```

As a side note, you really should avoid using scaffolding since it makes too many decisions and generalisations for you. You can use individual generators.

```
rails g model Transaction from_account_id:integer to_account_id:integer
rails g controller transactions
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how can I select from accounts name on the Transaction Form?